# Displaying information from an external file in C

Tags: c, file-io

How do I read in an external file and then either print the whole text or selected lines?

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("c:\\students.txt", "r");
```

I understand that reads the file but after that I am lost. Help please!!!

Do I need to read in binary or is text file acceptable?

Comment: It just opens the file, there's a big difference. To read from the file you must use the `fread()` call.

Comment: there are lots of ways to read from a file, most of which are preferable to fread() for many cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading data from file in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039936/reading-data-from-file-in-c)

Comment: Confused as to why both valid answers were downvoted....

Comment: @user2340574 - I recommend you go get a basic C programming book out of the library or look at some tutorials online like this one.  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer.  You're obviously struggling with the very basics.

Answer (score 0):

- You get a pointer to the file stream with `fopen()`
- `fread()` will only return **the amount** of actual data that the program
  could find inside your .txt file - It's very misleading. The main use is getting the **number of elements** for your loops. You can upload a file into your program, and print it on the screen without ever touching this function, if you know exactly what the file should already  have. Only use this if you don't know what's in your file.
- `getline()` is your go-to for printing out a specific line. No way around this one, and you'll need the specific library for it.

Here's an Example Code I wrote while doing a self-study on this, just showing how each of these are used, and printing out on **BOTH** the program, and a separate txt file outside the program. It doesn't have `getline()` however.

```
/*
Goals: 

Create an array of 5 values
Input 5 vales from a pre-created file, into the new array
Print out the 5 values into another file. 
Close the file. 
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DATAFILE "E:/Data.txt"
#define REPORT "E:/Report.txt"

//prototypes
FILE *Open_File();
void Consolodate_Array(int a_array[], FILE *file_pointer);
void Print_File(int a_array[], FILE *report_pointer);
void end_function(FILE *file_pointer, FILE *report_pointer);



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int array[5];

  FILE *Datatext = Open_File();
  //Declared "Datatext" to be equal to Open_File's Return value.
  //FILE itself is like Int, Double, Float, ect.
  FILE *ReportText = fopen(REPORT, "w"); 
  //Did the same as above, just not in a separate function. This gives us a 
  //Pointer to the REPORT.txt file, in write mode instead of read mode. 

  Consolodate_Array(array, Datatext);
  Print_File(array, ReportText);
  end_function(Datatext, ReportText);

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//This function should open the file and pass a pointer
FILE *Open_File()
{
  return fopen(DATAFILE, "rb");
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//This function should input the variables gotten for the file, into the array
void Consolodate_Array(int a_array[], FILE *file_pointer)
{
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
       fscanf(file_pointer, "%i", &a_array[i]);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//This function prints out the values into the second file, & at us too.
void Print_File(int a_array[], FILE *report_pointer)
{   
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   { 
      printf("%i\n", a_array[i]);
      fprintf(report_pointer, "%i\n", a_array[i]); 
   }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//This function closes the file.
void end_function(FILE *file_pointer, FILE *report_pointer)
{
   fclose(file_pointer);
   fclose(report_pointer);
   //closes both files we worked on. 
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted as this was a complete example albeit a little overkill :)

Comment: Hahah thanks Ramos =)
Was the first answer I made on Stack-overflow. Made it in the sort of answer I'd have gotten the most mileage out of, but guess not everyone thinks like I do